# Difference between Hamcrest-library jar and Hamcrest-all jar

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, assert

What is the difference between using the **hamcrest-library-1.3.jar** that comes bundled with Selenium Webdriver (I use v2.49) and **hamcrest-all-1.3.jar** found on the official website of Hamcrest https://code.google.com/archive/p/hamcrest/downloads

Is the hamcrest-library-1.3.jar sufficient or will I be missing out on any features by not having the hamcrest-all-1.3.jar configured?

There is also the **hamcrest-core-1.3.jar** that comes with Selenium Webdriver which is described as "(bare-bones minimum)" in their official webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hamcrest-all-1.3.jar** is not required and you won't be missing out on any features if you skip that jar.

As you have noted for Selenium WebDriver two jars file included in Reference Libraries are **hamcrest-core-1.3.jar** and **hamcrest-library-1.3.ja**r. These two covers all important packages and only thing you will be missing **org.hamcrest.generator.*** (if you need more info refer https://code.google.com/archive/p/hamcrest/wikis/HamcrestDistributables.wiki)